Endpoint not found when sending web push notifications through FCM
In our company, we provide web push notifications as a service for our customers. We've noticed a rise in 404 errors in the last days of June 2024 and messages like "A valid push subscription endpoint should be specified in the URL as such: https://fcm.googleapis.com/wp/... when sending push notifications through Firebase.
These errors come from a browser-generated endpoint created during user subscriptions, not something we control on our end. We've checked that those subscribers have, in fact, received messages in the past. Furthermore, the endpoint has not changed when recent users subscribe to the service, they're still in the format of "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/....".
I'm not sure from the posts here [2] and here [3] if we need to migrate something from our end in order to continue to use web push notifications through FCM (which is the only service we use). In addition to this, we haven't seen any changes in the codebase of the web push libraries that support the sending process from our end.
We are very concerned about our ability continue sending notifications and to the fact that once we receive any non-201 response, we should stop sending it to those subscribers, something that clips even more of the audiences of our clients.
Maybe related with [1]?
[1] Will FCM ditch the support of Web Push Protocol?
[2] https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/3C2Vq9pIWr4?pli=1
[3] Will FCM ditch the support of Web Push Protocol?


We've noticed a rise in 404 errors in the last days of June 2024

This issue started on 26 June 2024 and is described here:
https://pushpad.xyz/blog/fcm-returns-404-for-stale-push-subscriptions
Basically Google confirmed that there was a change in FCM and are now deleting subscriptions that didn't download the notifications from FCM for 9 months or more.
Given that, based on data collected on hundreds of millions of devices, we still have some doubts about this change in FCM. It seems that a few valid endpoints were also deleted (we see a lower number of clicks for some customers). If you also experience that please report the issue here:

https://issues.chromium.org/issues/349646659
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/353167420


I'm not sure from the posts here [2] and here [3] if we need to migrate something from our end in order to continue to use web push notifications through FCM

It depends:

If you have built something on the proprietary FCM SDK, you need to take action, otherwise all your subscriptions will stop working.
If you are using the Push API standard, no action is required.

We contacted Google FCM support directly and they confirmed that.
